# Race condition between two threads involving database update and reads

Tags: java, database, multithreading, redis

**Consider a situation:**

```
List = get_list_by_key(key) //get from redis
if(list.size() != 0)
{
  //do something
} else 
{
  add_to_list(key, value) //put to redis
}
```

The problem I'm facing is when two simultaneous threads come in, when list is empty, (I cannot afford to wait for another thread to start, which may never), any good way to handle this?

Ideally if block should be executed but in above situation it doesn't.

Edit: This code is part of an application running on a clustered environment, so synchronization might not be possible, **Also a lock is not feasible in my case since it, would block another thread (which I'm trying to avoid).**

Comment: Sounds like the whole block should be `synchronized` (or use some other locking mechanism) so only a single thread at at a time can run that entire code block.

Comment: **so synchronization might not be possible** : Maybe you can use a ```distributed lock```?

Comment: If you're talking about a clustered environment, I would guess that you're not really concerned with _multithreading_, but more about multiple processes and services accessing the same Redis. I'd suggest investigating transactions and optimistic locks or pessimistic locks, depending on your use-case. If you're using a framework to access Redis, that may provide you with a simple way of making a request transactional.

Comment: You can use [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to make the code atomic.

Answer (score 0):

lock the whole thing with synchronized and one thread will access that piece at a time, get from redis, update, save again in redis.

```
public synchronized void doStuff (String key, String value) {
  List = get_list_by_key(key) //get from redis
  if(list.size() != 0) {
    //do something
  } else {
  add_to_list(key, value) //put to redis
  }
}
```